# Facebook Posting to a Page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to the wall of a facebook page that I am administrator (not profile), however no luck. How do I achieve this ? I'm stucked at the page access token retrieval part.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import facebook
import urllib
import urlparse
import subprocess
import warnings

# Hide deprecation warnings. The facebook module isn't that up-to-date (facebook.GraphAPIError).
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)




# Parameters of your app and the id of the profile you want to mess with.
FACEBOOK_APP_ID     = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'


# Trying to get an access token. Very awkward.
oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  scope         = 'manage_pages',
                  response_type = 'token'
                  )
oauth_curl_cmd = ['curl',
                  'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)]
oauth_response = subprocess.Popen(oauth_curl_cmd,
                                  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)

try:
    oauth_access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(str(oauth_response))['access_token'][0]
except KeyError:
    print('Unable to grab an access token!')
    exit()
print oauth_access_token

facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)


# Try to post something on the wall.
try:
    fb_response = facebook_graph.put_wall_post('Hello from Python', \
                                               profile_id = FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID)
    print fb_response
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print 'Something went wrong:', e.type, e.message
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing this through the command line with curl as it is less secure and less reliable. You can do all of this with the urllib2 and json modules

to get the access token you just want to make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

so you would do:

```
url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials'
target=urllib2.urlopen(url)
token = target.read()[13:]
```

EDIT:
My bad, I forgot that facebook/oauth gives you the access token in plain text so you don't need the json module. I've updated the example to show what you should be doing. Note target.read() will give you the string 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' and then you are just parsing it to remove the identifier.

to see what response is go to the url and put in your information you will a json dict with acess_token.

the second half of [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) should have all the information you need.